# How to protect plumbing to an outbuilding from freezing?

Tags: plumbing

I'm planning plumbing to an outbuilding.

When I splice in to the water line, I'm thinking I should insert a shutoff valve with a weep hole ("stop and waste"). Then, if I leave for the winter, I can drain the line to protect from freezing.

Is this sensible?

The water line is 1" HDPE. Are there stop-and-waste valves with barbs for poly line?

Or should I use a pair of regular valves - one for supply, one for draining the line?

EDIT: I should note that our specified frost depth is only 12". The valve won't be very farbelow grade. Of course, maybe such a mild climate means this is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you will find a barbed fitting with all the features you are looking for. You can use a barbed to male threaded adapter, then a brass valve with waste drain. A little teflon tape and you should be good to go.